# Mencoder on Lion

Tags: macos, homebrew, encoding

Is there a way to install [`mencoder`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEncoder) on Lion, preferrably using homebrew?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`mencoder` is part of the MPlayer utility, and is installed as part of the MPlayer package on most systems. Installing MPlayer via Homebrew ( `brew install mplayer` ) will supply the `mencoder` binary as well.

```
$ brew list mplayer
/usr/local/Cellar/mplayer/1.1/bin/mplayer
/usr/local/Cellar/mplayer/1.1/bin/mencoder
/usr/local/Cellar/mplayer/1.1/share/man/ (2 files)
```